# Dots in index names in Internet Explorer 7 does not work

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

For example 
properties['stem.secid']
is interpreted by Internet Explorer 7 as
properties.stem.secid
and is thus not working.

Is there a solution or workaround to this problem?

Comment: Don't use dots in identifiers. ;-)

Comment: Of additional note is "numeric identifiers (those that are not a string) may not start with a zero"

Comment: @Marcel: Dots are not valid in identifiers, but are perfectly valid in strings, which is what the OP is using.

Comment: @Marcel - what about an identifier that comes from another data set which you don't control directly?   Probably the answer is to escape this data in some fashion...

Comment: @David - are you really certain that the problem is as you describe and not something else?  I don't have easy access to an IE7 anymore but I could swear that I have apps that would have broken if what you say is true... could be wrong

Comment: @Tim: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: @drachenstern, @larson4: This is all irrelevant. Any string is valid as a property name in JavaScript.

Comment: @larson4: you really should be able to access those properties using the square bracket notation, but I don't think it will get any beauty prize.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be mistaken here. At the very least, this isn't how IE9 works:

```
>> var x = { foo : { bar : 'hello' } }; 
>> x.foo.bar 
"hello" 
>> x['foo.bar'] 
undefined
```

Or more explicitly:

```
>> var x = {
    foo : {
        bar : 'hello'
    },
    'foo.bar' : 'goodbye'
}; 

>> x['foo.bar'] 
"goodbye"
```

Comment: Sure. Code works perfect in IE9 and Firefox. I worked around the issue by using the following workaround/solution
propArr = jQuery.makeArray(properties);

propArr['stem.secid'] works well.

Comment: @David ~ So you're relying on black magic for your solution rather than doing it right?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't true. Dots are perfectly valid in property names (indeed any string may be used as a property name) and are handled correctly by IE 7. The following works correctly in all browsers:

```
var o = {};
o['stem.secid'] = "foo";
alert(o.stem); // undefined
alert(o['stem.secid']); // foo
```

Answer (score -1):

This is by design. Why doesn't that work for what you want?

Javascript allows properties to be identified by bracket-string notation or by dotted notation as you've shown. This allows for the following to be equivalent:

```
my.obj.stem.secid = value
my['obj']['stem']['secid'] = value
```

But that allows us to programmatically select specific elements by specifying a key like thus:

```
var key1 = 'obj';
var key2 = 'stem';
var key3 = 'secid';
my[key1][key2][key3] = value
//or alternately just in parts:
my[key1].stem[key3] = value
```

but note that that would not be the same as if we did this

```
var key1 = 'obj';
var key2 = 'stem';
var key3 = 'secid';
my.key1.key2.key3 = value
```

And that is why you would use bracketed strings as segment identifiers.

Comment: I think you miss the point of the question: per spec, everything inside the square brackets should be regarded as *one* identifier, so `foo['bar.baz']` should be resolved to property `bar.baz` of object `foo`, not property `baz` of object `bar` inside object `foo`.

Comment: @Marcel I don't miss the point of the question, I try to explain that the behavior is what is expected, given the way javascript handles identifiers. I would point out that was my first line of my answer "that is by design" and that the reason is the rest of my post.